# arcpy.AddIndex_management error for in_memory variable

Tags: arcpy, error-999999, in-memory

I am trying to optimize a script that uses `addJoin_management`. To do this efficiently, I am attempting to add an attribute index on the join table. I am getting a generic error when i do this though.

> arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
>   Failed to execute (AddIndex).

My code does an intersect, dissolve, calculate acres, join and then re-calculate the acres column to the target table.

EDIT: See below for my solution.

Comment: I have been doing something very similar recently in model builder and can confirm that in_memory datasets do not support indices. I ended up using the %ScratchGDB% workspace in model builder

Comment: It's strange, I had the same problem where I needed to add an index to both layers I am joining, it is only one of them that fail though with an error along the lines of 'index exists'. While the other runs every time. 
Also, I write the line differently, in your case `arcpy.AddIndex_management(dissolved,"FID_Parcels_2013", "ID", 1, 1)` rather than spelling out the 'unique' and 'ascending' options.  Does "ID" stands for your index name? I run my data off disk so like @Hornbydd said it might be an in memory issue

Comment: Yes ID is the index name. I want to avoid writing anything to disk but it looks like I may have to in order to perform the addIndex operation.

Comment: did you try the, the other code? with 1,1 rather than spelling out the options? because I'd think it would give more than a generic 9999 error, if it is not a syntax issue...

Comment: I didnt get a chance to try that out. Ill give it a shot when i return to work monday. For now i am just writing the 'dissolved' to disk and deleting after I have completed all the other steps.

Comment: I revisited this issue and updated my original post with my work around.

Comment: I think you should cut/paste the answer (workaround) from your question into an answer.  It is perfectly acceptable and preferred to do this.

Comment: Ditto PolyGeo - @ians move your edit to an answer and accept. I learned a lot from this thread, and it deserves to have an accepted answer.

Comment: @Priscilla - done. Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My Solution:**
I was never able to get the in_memory variable working with AddIndex_management. I ended up using the arcpy.env.scratchGDB.

```
# in_memory variables do not work with AddIndex Management
# dissolve_out = "in_memory" + "\\" + "mem_dissolved" 

# The solution:
dissolve_out =  os.path.join(arcpy.env.scratchGDB, "scratch_dissolve_out")

arcpy.AddIndex_management(dissolve_out ,"FID_Parcels_2013", "ID", "UNIQUE", "ASCENDING")
```